# Windows logs off admin user when idle

Tags: administrator

I wish to keep my computer from doing this.  I don't know what happened but it is doing this everytime I am on the computer. I'm unfamiliar with how it works but would like to get answers for my problem. I have never backed up my computer as I don't know how.  This is my private machine and I do not have anyone else using it.

Comment: This is likely a setting in Power Settings in the Control Panel. In order to give an answer on how to change this setting, I need to know what version of Windows you're running. It's probably Windows 7, but it could be Windows Vista, Windows XP or Windows 8.

Comment: @moses I am not sure there is any specific setting in Power Options to log off users when machine is idle.

Comment: @GaneshR., look at my answer then, this explains it

Comment: @DaveRook Yep, that's the one I meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the power options.

Go to Control Panel, open power options

Click on "Change plan settings" and here it gives you some sliders to alter the times. So, as you can see where I high lighted, I would recommend just changing the length of this time, or turning it off.

There is also the option to change advanced power settings which do suggest you open up and review to see if there is anything else there which may be helpful.

[image]

---

Also, right click on your desktop and select personalise. Then, click on screen saver. In the new tab, it will give you a check box to return to display logon screen after X minutes. This may be configured and if the screen saver is blank, then it would appear as if the monitor display is just turned off and not obvious that it is a screen saver.

[image]

---

As an aside and in regards to backing up, look at this video: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/back-up-your-files It should help to learn how to back up your files.

And even better, is this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/back-up-your-programs-system-settings-and-files